# PHP Type Hinting: array supported, object NOT?

Tags: php, oop

Am I missing something or there really is no support for generic object type hinting in PHP 5.x?

I find it really strange that hinting arrays is supported while hinting objects is not, at least not out of the box.

I'd like to have something like this:

```
function foo(object $o)
```

Just as we have:

```
function foo(array $o)
```

Example of possible use: methods of an objects collection class.

Workaround: using an interface "Object" implemented by all classes or extending all classes from a generic class "Object" and writing something like this:

```
function foo(Object $o)
```

Well, that just ain't cute.

Using `stdClass` as the type hint doesn't work:

> Catchable fatal error: Argument 1
>   passed to c::add() must be an instance
>   of stdClass, instance of b given

Comment: Don't use concrete types for type hinting. Either use interfaces, or read about duck typing.

Comment: If I'm to walk the no concrete types path I'd rather use is_object(). But that's not the point of this discussion.

Comment: Look, PHP is a very inconsistent language, in which objects do not inherit from a single class, like in Java. The fact there's no type hinting for general objects is an oversight indeed, but I think you have to pass this point and prepare for other strange things.

Comment: I'm curious, how does this general object type hinting helps you? How is it better than just check that it `is_object`?

Comment: How is array hinting better than is_array()? Since array hinting is supported, I'd expect the same for objects.

Comment: I don't believe that array type hinting is better than `is_array`? Catching a type hinting error involves more steps as opposed to checking with `is_array` and throwing an Exception. Exceptions can be easily caught, while type hinting errors force you to have an error_handler, which may indeed throw an Exception, but there are problems with error_handlers overwriting. Anyway, that's my opinion. Do as you like. Personally, I don't like your approach.

Comment: @IonuțG.Stan `is_array` checking and throwing exceptions in each function is easier than than setting up a global exception handler? You gotta be kidding me.

Comment: @SalmanPK a global error handler means that you can't handle the exception at call site, which is sometimes desirable. You can't wrap a call to a function with such a type hint around a try/catch block. It wasn't possible last time I checked at least.

Comment: Umm yeah that's a trade-off but I don't know why would anyone knowingly pass a variable of an illegal type to a function. That's just silly.

Comment: @SalmanPK the real problem appears when the type-hinted function/method lies a few layers of abstraction below. You may pass the correct argument type, but the wrong value for what that library expects a few function calls below, which might cause a bad argument type in the end. If you'd like to catch that error and transform it to something meaningful based on the locale state where you made the initial call you can't. If you have a global exception handler you'll also need some global state in order to act differently. I usually keep the global handler for logging exceptions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it can't be done. I wasn't missing anything.

Comment: Since PHP 7.2 you can finally declare the way you wanted:

`function functionName(object $someObjectVariable)`

See the table named "Valid types" on the following page:
(https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration)

Answer (score 7):

Since type hinting should make the client code adapt to your API, your solution with accepting interfaces seems just about right.

Look at it this way: `yourMethod(array $input)` gives `yourMethod()` an array to use, thereby you know [exactly which native functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.array.php) that applies and can be used by `yourMethod()`.

If you specify your method like: `yourSecondMethod(yourInterface $input)` you'd also know which methods that can be applied to `$input` since you know about/can lookup which set of rules that accompanies the interface `yourInterface`.

In your case, accepting any object seems wrong, because you don't have any way of knowing which methods to use on the input. Example:

```
function foo(Object $o) {
    return $o->thisMethodMayOrMayNotExist();
}
```

(Not implying that syntax is valid)

Comment: That's not the case for an objects collection class which will be acting as a (pseudo) container that won't be invoking any methods on its children nor will it use any of their attributes / properties.
Knowing a variable is an object also makes it possible to use lots of native functions on it, so I don't really see your point.

Comment: How about using a type hint such as SplObjectStorage or ArrayObject?

Comment: There is \stdClass for simple container objects

Answer (score 6):

I feel your pain, but I can't find a way of doing it either.

Despite what a number of other posters have said, it makes perfect sense to want 'Object' type hinting; they just haven't considered a scenario that requires it.

I am trying to do some work with the reflection API, and because of that I don't care what class is passed to my function.  All I care is that it's an object.  I don't want an int, a float, a string or an array.  I want an object.  Given that reflection is now part of PHP, it definitely makes sense to have object type hinting.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot just say "object" when type casting an object... you must define WHICH object you are expecting.

From: http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php

```
class MyClass
{
    /**
     * A test function
     *
     * First parameter must be an object of type OtherClass
     */
    public function test(OtherClass $otherclass) {
        echo $otherclass->var;
    }


    /**
     * Another test function
     *
     * First parameter must be an array
     */
    public function test_array(array $input_array) {
        print_r($input_array);
    }
}

// Another example class
class OtherClass {
    public $var = 'Hello World';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The best way to enforce this would be to create a degenerate interface called `Object`. A degenerate interface means it has no defined methods.

```
interface Object {

   // leave blank

}
```

Then in your base classes, you can implement `Object`.

```
class SomeBase implements Object {

   // your implementation

}
```

You can now call your function as you wanted to

```
function myFunc (Object $obj);

myFunc($someBase);
```

If you pass any object which inherits from your `Object` interface, this type hint will pass. If you pass in an array, int, string etc, the type hint will fail.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is probably the closest you're going to get in PHP, but it does mean every class you create has to implement the `Object` interface, which is really a lot of overhead for something as simple as this. Ahhhhh, PHP..

Comment: The OP already described this strategy in the question as a possible workaround, and it kind of sucks; this won't let you pass instances built-in classes or classes defined in third-party libraries.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another example where it is required...

I've created a class to implement record locking. Records being one of a number of different object types. The locking class has several methods which require an object (the one to be locked) but don't care what type of object it is.

E.g.

```
public static function lockRecord($record, User $user, $timeout=null)
{
    if(!is_object($record)) throw new \InvalidException("Argument 1 must be an object.");

    $lock=new Lock();
    $lock->setRecord($record);
    $lock->setUser($user);
    $lock->setTimeout($timeout);
    $lock->activate();
    return($lock);
}
```

You'll see that my solution was to use is_object() and throw an exception, but I'd far rather be able to do it with type hinting instead.

Ok, so not the end of the world, but I think it's a shame.

Answer (score 1):

Objects in php are not subclasses of some StdClass or Object as it is in other  OOP languages. So there is no way of type hinting the object. But I see your point because sometimes you want to make sure that the Object is being passed, so I guess the only way is to raise the issue manually.

```
public function yourFunction($object){
    if(is_object($object)){
        //TODO: do something
    }else{
        throw new InvalidArgumentException;
    }
}
```

As of php 5.4 there is also a type hint *callable*. 
See php manual http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.callable.php

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to hint `object` when you can hint an actual class name instead - this would be much more useful. Also remember that you can't hint `int`,`float`, `bool`, `string` or `resource` either.

Comment: Why would you want to hit an array? Remember all those other types you can't hint... Since there is no common base class from which all PHP classes descend, it makes sense to be able to hint an object, just as it makes to hint an array. My opinion, but I doubt I'm alone on this one.

Comment: Just because you cannot think of an instance for type-hinting to a generic object, doesn't mean the need never exists.The comment by Rikki is a perfect example. The fact that you cannot type hint for int, float, bool, string and resource is also an oversight, in my opinion. There have been plenty of instances where I'd have preferred to explicitly limit an argument to only an integer. So instead, I'm stuck using "is_int" nonsense calls.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static function cloneObject($source)
{
    if ($source === null)
    {
        return null;
    }

    return unserialize(serialize($source));
}
```

This is where you would need it.

Comment: To improve the quality of your answer, please include how/why your post solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Since **PHP 7.2** you can finally declare the way you wanted:

`function functionName(object $someObjectVariable)`

See the table named "Valid types" at this page:
https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.type-declaration