# Dynamic type-hinting in Laravel

Tags: php, oop, reflection, laravel-5.1, type-hinting

I was wondering if it is possible to use type-hinting dynamically.

Example:

```
class Foo {
    __construct(Baz $baz) {
    }
}

class Bar {
    __construct() {
    }

    action() {
        $baz = new Baz;
        return new Foo($baz);
    }
}

class Baz {
    __construct() {
    }
}
```

I am intending to do it in a generic way so the class will be reusable but in the same time to keep the type hinting:

```
class Foo {
        __construct(Object $object) {
        }
}
```

Comment: You can type-hint to an interface

Comment: Yes. This is how it works but I do not know what object I recive. It could be Bar $bar / Baz $baz etc. I can make a check based on "instanceof" but I was hoping to find a better way.

Comment: There isn't one... you can't type hint to the level of a generic 'object', only for specific classes, objects that implement an interface or that are extensions from a parent class

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7839059/type-hinting-for-any-object?rq=1

Comment: Thanks. So I will probably make an "instanceof" check from an array or something.

Comment: `instanceof` is usually a bad design. What exactly are you trying to achieve here (i.e. what are Foo/Baz classes)?

Comment: Well I want to refactor the code so for example these classes could be some Laravel models passed to a generic model observer class (created, updated, deleted). Or I can consider a different approach: using a trait.

Comment: The problem you have is exactly solved by using interfaces. It sometimes is also called polymorphism, afaik

Comment: If these are always models that extend Laravel's `Eloquent` Model, then you can type-hint to that

Comment: @MarkBaker Do you mean `__construct(Model $object)` ? It should work. Thanks :)